# Can someone interpret the for loop for me?

Tags: c, string, reverse

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 10

void reverse(char s[]);
void getline(char b[], int lim);

int main() {
char s[MAXLINE];
getline(s, MAXLINE);
reverse(s);
return 0;
}

void reverse(char s[]) {
    int i;
    int len = 0;
    for (i=0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        len = len + 1;
    }
    char b[len + 1];
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        b[(len - 1) - i] = s[i];
    b[len] = '\0';
    }
    printf("%s : %s\n", s, b);
}

void getline(char b[], int lim) {
    char c;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < lim-1 && (c = getchar())!= EOF && (c!='\n'); ++i) {
        b[i] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
        b[i] = '\n';
    }
}
```

why am i getting an error for the get line unction? It says in Xcode "conflicting types for 'get line'. Also in another error, it says "Too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 2?

Also can someone explain the order of evaluation for the "condition" part of the for loop? (I'm talking about the &&'s). Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Try **man getline**. That should clear things up... (meaning there is already a `getline` function defined by libc.)

Comment: *can someone explain the order of evaluation for the "condition" part of the for loop? (I'm talking about the &&'s).* Left to right. Short circuits (stops) if (or when) one fails.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { b[(len - 1) - i] = s[i]; b[len] = '\0'; }` should be `for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { b[(len - 1) - i] = s[i]; } b[len] = '\0';`.  Mis-placed `}`.

Comment: `for (i=0; i < lim-1 && (c = getchar())!= EOF && (c!='\n'); ++i)` the `&&` imposes a second condition on the loop which is in reality a misplaced method of flushing the input buffer of any remaining characters following reading input from stdin. Here, the loop attempts to simulate line input using `getchar()` to read any characters in stdin.

Comment: Note: In `getline()`, `char c;` --> `int c;`.

Comment: why should it be int c instead of char c? I'm trying to store a string into an array haha. Also, what do you mean by stdin? thanks a lot! I'm sorry

Comment: It must be `int` in order to correctly determine equality to `EOF`.

Comment: This is not how to learn. Get a good text book.

Comment: I'm using a review book to get back into C. Do you recommend any specific books, examples, exercises etc? Thanks.

Comment: Okay but in terms of "hello123" or "hello" would putting "char c" be fine instead of "int c"?

Answer (score 0):

(1)..Your program is correct.But,already one library function `getline` is exist in library.We know that predefined function's prototype declarations are present in header file.For `getline` predefined function, declaration is already present in `stdio.h`...In your program, you are also declared prototype for `getline` .We know well that It is not possible two declarations for one function.So only you got error.Try to run your program with othername for that function...

(2)..`for (i=0; i < lim-1 && (c = getchar())!= EOF && (c!='\n'); ++i)`

In for loop you are checking three conditions..you are checking for '\n' also.so,You should give input as string format only.But actually it is not string.You should give characters as input continuously without pressing ENTER.